# ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

> ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at
> '/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Runner/Info.plist'
> does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally
> does not contain an executable, consider removing the
> CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a
> CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party
> framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an
> update to address this issue.

How to resolve this issue? I searched my entire project, I couldn't find this path anywhere In the project, and all the missing CFBundleExecutables CFBundlePackageTypes is in BNDL

Answer (score 0):

Please check Info.plist added to Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phase. If so just remove it from Copy Bundle Resources.